redis-rails and acl getting NOPERM with turbo broadcast
We are trying to set passwords on our redis.
redis.conf:
user default on >xxxxxxxx ~* +@all
user user01 on >xxxxxxxx ~* +@all

In our environment variables we have:
REDIS_URL=redis://user01:xxxxxx@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:6379/1

and cable.yml has:
production:
  adapter: redis
  url: <%= ENV.fetch("REDIS_URL") { "redis://localhost:6379/1" } %>
  channel_prefix: my_app_production

But when we try and do a turbo broadcast we get:
[a-b-c-d-e] Failed to process job: NOPERM this user has no permissions to access one of the channels used as arguments (redis://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:6379/1)

For completeness here's the versions:
$ redis-server --version
Redis server v=7.0.15 sha=00000000:0 malloc=jemalloc-5.3.0 bits=64 build=d81b8ff71cfb150e

  * redis (5.3.0)
  * redis-client (0.22.2)


